# Moloquent без Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, composer

Хочу работать с MongoDB через Moloquent без Laravel. Установил через `composer require moloquent/moloquent`, создал `index.php`, написал следующий код:

```
<?php

require_once( __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php' );

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
// use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
// use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Moloquent\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

$mongoconfig = [
    'driver'   => 'mongodb',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => 27017,
    'database' => 'test',
    'username' => 'mongoadmin',
    'password' => '12345678'
    'options' => [
        'db' => 'admin'
    ]
];

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->getDatabaseManager()->extend( 'mongodb', function( $config )
{
    return new \Moloquent\Connection( $mongoconfig );
});

class User extends Eloquent {
    // protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'posts';
}

var_dump( User::count() );
```

Ругается вот таким словами:

```
2017/07/03 05:06:48 [error] 4379#4379: *8 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in /var/www/test/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php:1041
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/test/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php(1007): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection('mongodb')
#1 /var/www/test/vendor/moloquent/moloquent/src/Eloquent/Model.php(558): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getConnection()
#2 /var/www/test/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php(814): Moloquent\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#3 /var/www/test/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php(798): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
#4 /var/www/test/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php(1357): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQuery()
#5 /var/www/test/vendor/moloquent/moloquent/src/Eloquent/Model.php(590): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('count', Array)
#6 /var/www/test/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php(1369): Moloquent\Eloquent\M" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: test.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "test.dev"
```

Подключение валидное, база `test` существует, коллекция`posts` существует, в ней 1 запись для теста. Что я делаю не так?

Инфу брал частично [здесь](https://moloquent.github.io/master/basic/) и [здесь](https://github.com/illuminate/database).

P.S. Выбор Moloquent не критичен, но желателен. Хотелось бы разобраться на будущее вообще в подходе к такого рода решениям, потому что Moloquent далеко не единственный модуль, который хотелось бы использовать отдельно. Однако, чтобы не выходить за рамки данного вопроса, прошу помощи только по Moloquent, в остальном попробую потом разобраться сам, ориентируясь на данный вопрос. Спасибо за понимание.

P.P.S. Закомментированные строки я оставил чтобы показать с чем я пробовал "играться" и не получилось.